# Remove duplicates in columns BUT retain the BLANK and NULL cell

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a 3 columns of serial numbers, IMEI numbers and phone numbers.  I want to remove the duplicates from each column BUT keep the BLANK and NULL cells.
Is there a measure to remove the duplicates in all 3 columns BUT keep the NULL and BLANK rows and how do I implement this measure ?  The table is named "serial" and the columns are named "IMEI", "Serial Number" and "Phone Number".

Comment: So, by duplicates, you mean where all three cells from the three columns in the same row are identical?

Comment: And what do you consider the difference between NULL and BLANK rows?

Comment: Some cells contain the word "null" where others are just blank

Comment: 3 columns...IMEI, Phone Number and Serial Number...each column may have duplicates of each category...plus some cells are populated with the word "null" or are just blank.  I need to retain the nulls and blank cells.  The data sources do not populate the columns completely.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data for both source and expected output here [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: So it is duplicates in each individual column that you want to remove independant of other columns - not duplicate rows?  So each column may end up a different length than the others?

Comment: Does the data in the columns need to stay in the same order or if it comes back sorted is that ok?

Comment: I need to remove duplicates of the 3 columns and keep their order...S/N with IMEI with Phone #...I need to be able to keep the empty cells and cells with the word null.